# Android - get device orientation after taking a photo

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, device-orientation

I want to get the device orientation, which theoretically should work using this:

```
getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

However I noticed that sometimes, after I have called the camera using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFile(1); // create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
// start the image capture Intent
intent.putExtra(GlobalDefines.IMAGE_NR, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_1);
```

and after I have taken the image, when I try to get the device orientation in onActivityResult (which is called after the picture is taken) the device orientation states "landscape" mode, although I took the picture in portrait mode and the device is held in portrait mode.

The strange thing is that this only occurs in around 3 out of 10 times. It appears that while taking the picture the device orientation is internally changed to "landscape mode" (even though the image is taken in portrait mode), and after the picture is taken, it takes a while until the device realizes that it is in portrait mode.

What can I do about it?

Comment: You better use the image orientation, as some devices + camera programs perform weird orientation changes.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, that's why I wanted to know the device orientation (would take longer to explain why exactly), main issue is that my exif-image-data seems to be strange as well...

Comment: Some devices doesn't write EXIF data too. You must check the orientation from `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION`. Anyways, I always check all the orientations in cascade: MediaStore, EXIF, device.

Comment: Yeah, but checking the device orientation is tricky since it returns the wrong value sometimes - do you maybe know why?

Comment: Which device is that? Maybe its orientation (accelerometer) sensor has HW problems?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note is a mess with orientation changes after taking a photo, for example. Anyways, the user can always take the photo and change the orientation before accepting it, so device orientation must be your last chance of guessing the recently taken photo orientation.

Answer (score 3):

If the device does not write reliable EXIF orientation, this may be caused by HW problems with the orientation sensor (accelerometer). There is no sense in checking the orientation in your app if this is the case.

I can explain why sometimes your activity will not report correct (portrait) orientation in `onActivityResult()` after taking a picture via Intent, and how this orientation can be sensed in a more robust manner. But unfortunately, this will be in vain.

You cannot rely on the orientation of the device at the moment your app receives control back from the camera app, because after the end user actually captures a picture, she will preview it, probably make another attempt, and finally accept (or reject) the photo. During all this lengthy process *after* capture, the device may be rotated many times, consciously or unconsciously, by the end user. So, if you cannot rely on EXIF orientation, but can rely on the device sensors, you have no choice but *[use a Camera object](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)*, taking the picture within your app.

Now, for the record, here is the outline of explanation I mentioned in the second paragraph.

When your app receives `onActivityResult()` callback, it may happen after your Activity had been destroyed by the system (to free more memory for the Camera app). You have no control on whether this will happen, but you can know whether this was the case when control is returned back to your app.

In this case, your Activity will not know its orientation yet. It determines this orientation later, just before the `onResume()` callback. Therefore, you cannot blindly rely on the Activity orientation when inside `onActivityResult()`. You should read the accelerometer sensor directly, and calculate whether the orientation is landscape or portrait (see [`OrientationEventListener`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/view/OrientationEventListener.java) as examaple).

Unfortunately, this is only a theoretical option, as I explained above. And luckily, when you use a custom Camera, you can simply use the above `OrientationEventListener` class in your activity to determine the orientation reliably (to the extent the HW sensors are reliable).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But you are saying that I should implement my own camera and not use an external app for that, aren't you?

Comment: I would start with trying to understand why the EXIF flag is not working. Also, it is very important to prove that the HW sensor is working correctly. But you are right, the summary of my answer is: _if you cannot rely on EXIF orientation, but can rely on the device sensors, you have no choice but use a Camera object, taking the picture within your app_.

Comment: What you said regarding the destruction of the Activity to free memory for the camera might be the the reason for the inconsistent behaviour. I changed some settings so less memory is used, don't know if it will work like this forever. 
I am showing the picture that was taken in a Dialogfragment - might it be a possibility to wait, let's say 0,5 seconds, before getting the device orientation, and then display the DialogFragment with that image?

Comment: As I explained above, you cannot trust orientation of the device when control is returned to your app, so it is not worthwhile to look for workarounds for activity getting recreated. Please understand: reducing memory consumption is always good, but you can never know how tightly the memory is crowded in real life. There are robust techniques to restore the activity state correctly on return from photo capture intent (you can find some on SO).

Comment: Okay, I know how to save a part of the activity's state, but I don't know how that would affect the ability to get the device orientation correctly?

Comment: No it won't, because you cannot control the end user behavior between launching the external intent and return from it. Taking the desired picture and approving it may involve many orientation changes.